# Using Firebase Authentication with new @App protocol

Tags: ios, firebase, swiftui

I am new to iOS development and am struggling to implement Firebase phone authentication with the new @App protocol in SwiftUI. The documentation for Firebase is written for UIKit, and the tutorials online for SwiftUI use AppDelegate and SceneDelegate instead of the new @main protocol in the App struct.

My concrete questions are as follows: How/where would I inject this authentication state class I have created?

```
import Foundation
class AuthenticationState: NSObject,  ObservableObject
{
    @Published var loggedInUser: User?
    @Published var isAuthenticating = false
    @Published var error: NSError?
    
    static let shared = AuthenticationState();
    
    private let auth = Auth.auth();
    fileprivate var currentNonce: String?
    
    func login(with loginOption: LoginOption) {
            self.isAuthenticating = true
            self.error = nil

            switch loginOption {
                case .signInWithApple:
                    handleSignInWithApple()
            }
        }

        func signup(email: String, password: String, passwordConfirmation: String) {
            // TODO
        }

       private func handleSignInWithApple() {
            // TODO
        }
}
```

Secondly, the AuthenticationState class does not know about Firebase Auth object, I assume because it is incorrectly configured. So far, I am configuring Firebase in an AppDelegate class:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase


class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
        [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    
    
    return true
  }
    
            
    
   
    }
```

Whereas, I also have a MapworkApp.swift file, which I believe is supposed to replace AppDelegate, but I am unsure:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
@main
struct MapworkApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}

struct MapworkApp_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Text("Hello, World!")/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/
    }
}
```

The runtime errors I currently receive:

```
020-12-16 13:22:34.416917-0700 Mapwork[1351:332863] 7.3.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) to your application initialization. Read more: 
2020-12-16 13:22:34.417240-0700 Mapwork[1351:332633] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The default FIRApp instance must be configured before the default FIRAuthinstance can be initialized. One way to ensure that is to call `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) in the App Delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in Swift).'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1863a586c 0x19b314c50 0x18629e4a4 0x102bc8918 0x1028465d8 0x1028466f4 0x102845c1c 0x102845be4 0x102ec96c0 0x102ecb1f8 0x18a32c5bc 0x102845c64 0x102854aa0 0x102854cbc 0x18cdba724 0x102854c18 0x102855028 0x185fda6b0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The default FIRApp instance must be configured before the default FIRAuthinstance can be initialized. One way to ensure that is to call `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) in the App Delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in Swift).'
Message from debugger: The LLDB RPC server has exited unexpectedly. Please file a bug if you have reproducible steps.
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated as the docs online are now inapplicable.

Comment: You don't need the AppDelegate. Within MapworkApp.swift file, add an init() function and within the init call FirebaseApp.configure().

Comment: When attempting this I receive a compiler error, "init cannot be used as a keyword here"

Comment: init() is a function. It should look like:          init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    } ... put it outside of the body.

Comment: Unfortunately, after doing this, I still receive the same runtime errors above. Thank you for the help all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For many Firebase APIs, you don't need to use the `AppDelegate` approach. Instead, you can get away with initialising Firebase in your app's initialiser, like so:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

@main
struct MapworkApp: App {
  init() {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
  }
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
    }
  }
}
```

This works well for apps that use Cloud Firestore and Firebase Authentication (Sign in with Apple).

For some of Firebase's SDKs you need to implement an `AppDelegate`. To do so, implement your `AppDelegate` like this:

```swift
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    print("Application is starting up. ApplicationDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.")
    return true
  }
  
  // ... add any callbacks your app might require
}
```

Then, connect your `App` to the `AppDelegate` like this:

```swift
@main
struct MapworkApp: App {
  @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
  
  init() {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
  }
  
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
    }
  }
}
```

You might have to move the call to `FirebaseApp.configure()` to the `AppDelegate`. In this case, your `AppDelegate` and `App` might look like this (you can keep them in the same file, if you like):

```swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    return true
  }
}

@main
struct MapworkApp: App {
  @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
  
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
    }
  }
}
```

To learn more about this, check out my articles about the new application life cycle:

- [Firebase and the new SwiftUI 2 Application Life Cycle - SwiftUI 2](https://peterfriese.dev/swiftui-new-app-lifecycle-firebase/)
- [The Ultimate Guide to the SwiftUI 2 Application Life Cycle - SwiftUI 2](https://peterfriese.dev/ultimate-guide-to-swiftui2-application-lifecycle/)

This sample app I wrote shows how to build a simple to-do list app with SwiftUI and Firebase: [peterfriese/MakeItSo](https://github.com/peterfriese/MakeItSo). The latest version of the code follows the new SwiftUI 2 Application Life Cycle, and includes *Sign in with Apple*.